# Cannot make input:focus overwrite default setting

Tags: css, forms, focus

I am trying to make a CSS style for a form using a border-bottom style that goes to a green box. However I see that the input:focus syntax does not work, and it shows the default focus style. Can anyone tell me how to overwrite the default focus style? Thank you.

```
<style>
.input1{
    border:0px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #999999;
}
.input1:focus{
    border:1px solid green;
}
</style>

<form action="">
<div>
  <input class="input1" type="text" id="texto" >
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it works, you are missing `outline: none;`

```html
<style>
.input1{
    border:0px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #999999;
}
.input1:focus{
    border:1px solid green;
    outline: none;
}
</style>

<form action="">
<div>
  <input class="input1" type="text" id="texto" >
</div>
</form>
```